# How to add addition script to existing validation class

Tags: javascript, validation, prototype-js, form-validation

I need to increase the **validate-password class length to 8 characters**.

How can I add that script in that validate-password class?

**Note:**

1. I don't want to create a new validation class
2. I don't want to add any class name (`validate-length`) to the password field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way that should work and no need to modify a core JS file. Just drop it into a custom JS file and ensure it's included *after* `validation.js`.

```
Validation.add('validate-password', 'Please enter 8 or more characters. Leading or trailing spaces will be ignored.', function(v) {
    var pass=v.strip(); /*strip leading and trailing spaces*/
    return !(pass.length>0 && pass.length < 8);
});
```

It essentially just replaces the callback validation method that is originally set in `validation.js` with one that checks for 8 characters or more.

I'd be curious to know why you don't want to add the validate-length field as it seems like an easier approach to me.

**NOTE**: I haven't used this personally I just whipped it up on the demo store and tested it briefly.

Comment: I'm curious why the return `!()` when `return pass.length>0 && pass.length >= 8` will work and (to me) is more legible?

Comment: @philwinkle I agree. I just copy/pasted what was in `validation.js` to keep it consistent.